# Where does gas comes from when I create a new Contract in a Contract

Tags: contract-development, gas, gas-estimate

Let's say I am creating a contract from another contract by calling a function in a parent contract, is the gas required to create new contract included in running the function that creates new contract?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.15;

contract Test {
    bool public active = true;
    address public owner;
    address public contract_address;

    uint public amountReceived;

    address[] public activeContracts;
    uint256 public gasLeft;

    function () payable {
        amountReceived = msg.value;
        gasLeft = msg.gas;
    }

    function Test() {
        owner = msg.sender;
        contract_address = this;
        gasLeft = msg.gas;
    }

    function updateStatus() {
        active = false;
    }

    function kill() {
        selfdestruct(owner);
        gasLeft = msg.gas;
    }

    function createSubContract() {
        address newContractAddress = new SubTest();
        activeContracts.push(newContractAddress);
        gasLeft = msg.gas;
    }
}

contract SubTest {

    address public owner;
    address public contract_address;

    uint256 public amountReceived;
    uint256 public gasLeft;

    function () payable {
        amountReceived = msg.value;
        gasLeft = msg.gas;
    }

    function SubTest() {
        owner = msg.sender;
        contract_address = this;
        gasLeft = msg.gas;
    }

    function kill() {
        selfdestruct(owner);
        gasLeft = msg.gas;
    }

}
```

Here is a sample contract I am testing. Inorder to create a subcontract I call the function createSubContract, does gas required for calling this function include the gas required to create the contract?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You have to take care of assigning enough gas to your `createSubContract()` function call to be able to cover ***all*** the gas usage of ***all*** the subsequent calls originated from `createSubContract()`.

Although this gas assignment to sub-calls can be done in a more fine tuned way, i.e. you don't have to forward all the gas of your transaction to the sub-call as it is explained [here](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/introduction-to-smart-contracts.html?highlight=transaction%20gas#message-calls):

> A contract can decide how much of its remaining gas should be sent
>   with the inner message call and how much it wants to retain. If an
>   out-of-gas exception happens in the inner call (or any other
>   exception), this will be signalled by an error value put onto the
>   stack. In this case, only the gas sent together with the call is used
>   up. In Solidity, the calling contract causes a manual exception by
>   default in such situations, so that exceptions “bubble up” the call
>   stack.

In the future, the Metropolis hardfork will allow contracts to pay for gas. Check it out [here](https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/12/04/ethereum-research-update/) the *EIP 86 (account security abstraction)* paragraph.